# More character to scanner?

Tags: java, integer, java.util.scanner

I have a Scanner that gets an int like this

```
Scanner telnumscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Entrez phone number: \n");
int telnum = telnumscanner.nextInt();
```

I'm inputting a phone number style int there (0000000000--10 numbers) but when I enter the number, it crashes.

Comment: You might be going over the max value for int which is `2,147,483,647`. Since you haven't said what the exception was this is only a random guess. Unless you need to do some math with this number I would just use a String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reading a number that's too big to be held by an `int` type into an integer variable. In general, you shouldn't be storing phone number information in a numeric data type. Consider storing this information in a `String`.

See `telnumscanner.nextLine()`

Answer (score 2):

Because the allowed range of a Java `int` is between `-2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647`. Trying to read in a 10 digit value higher than `2,147,483,647` will yield an exception.

To solve, instead of using `nextInt()`, use [`nextLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong()) and read the input into a variable of type `long`. Alternatively, don't use a numeric type to store phone numbers, but store it as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Try storing it as a long.

```
long telnum = telnumscanner.next();
```

A long can store a value from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

You also can just use next() instead of nextLong() I believe. Someone correct me if I am wrong.